# SendGrid or Devise Conflict with Mail Gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise, actionmailer, sendgrid

I just configured ActionMailer to use SendGrid so that I could use it with Devise emails. The email part is working perfectly, but now I can't complete a migration. The error I get is '**TypeError: Mail is not a module**' and is shown in the code block below.

```
$ rake db:migrate
rake aborted!
TypeError: Mail is not a module
.../ruby-2.3.4/gems/mail-2.7.0/lib/mail.rb:3:in `<top (required)>'
.../ruby-2.3.4/gems/activesupport-5.0.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:293:in `require'
.../ruby-2.3.4/gems/activesupport-5.0.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:293:in `block in require'
.../ruby-2.3.4/gems/activesupport-5.0.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:259:in `load_dependency'
.../ruby-2.3.4/gems/activesupport-5.0.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:293:in `require'
```

I *think* the issue has to do with the fact that the ActionMailer gem depends on the Mail gem (which includes a 'mail' module called on mail.rb:3), and there are classes called 'mail' in 'devise/test/mailers/email_changed_test.rb' and 'devise/test/mailers/confirmation_instructions_test.rb' as well.

Maybe this conflict is caused by a rails/gem version incompatibility? (I'm using rails 5.0.4, mail 2.7.0, devise 4.3.0.) Or maybe I'm completely missing the point?

Comment: Okay, it looks like if I remove 'include SendGrid' from a rake task, I can successfully run rake. However, then I cannot successfully run a rake task that includes sending email through SendGrid. Interestingly, leaving 'include SendGrid' in the ApplicationController does NOT create the same errors that I was receiving before (or hasn't yet created errors).

Comment: I have the same problem, and it works when I remove `include SendGrid` ... Did you find a solution?

Comment: @MahmoudM.Abdel-Fattah Well I can't remember exactly how I resolved that exact issue back in Feb, but I did run into a similar issue recently, and this is how I fixed it (or got around it)... Instead of including SendGrid in the rake task, I put it in a mailer file (e.g., `class DeviseMailer < ApplicationMailer`), and created a method in that mailer that actually does the SendGrid function to send an email. Then I called that method from the rake task. Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer here:
https://github.com/sendgrid/sendgrid-ruby/blob/master/TROUBLESHOOTING.md#rails-specifics

Namespace collision between Rails own `Mail` class and sendgrid class `Mail`. To avoid that issues please use `SendGrid::Mail` instead.

Possibility of a namespace collision between the sendgrid class `Email` and your own defined `Email` class. To avoid these issues, you can skip the `include SendGrid` line and use the `SendGrid::` prefix for Email. Please see this SO answer for specifics.